# Smooth function whose zeros cannot be computed

Tags: real-analysis, logic

Is there a constructive example (i.e. given by explicit formulas) of a smooth function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and a number $x \in \mathbb R$ such that there exists no way to establish whether $f(x) = 0$, using the standard foundation of mathematics?

Comment: I think this question needs some clarification. First of all, what do you mean by "given by explicit formulas"? and what do you mean by "using standard foundations of mathematics"? For example, if a function is defined in terms of an integral, is it "given by explicit formulas"? Fifth degree and higher polynomials are unsolvable by radicals, but I'm not sure thats what you mean.

Comment: @user140776: Yes, an integral counts as a formula. By “the standard foundation of mathematics”, I mean ZFC, plus any of the usual, classically equivalent ways to construct the real numbers and define the usual concepts in analysis.

Comment: There are polynomials, but in several variables, with integer coefficients, which have roots if and only if ZFC is inconsistent. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes! Thanks!

Comment: http://edoc.mpg.de/get.epl?fid=101809&did=635058&ver=0

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32892/does-anyone-know-a-polynomial-whose-lack-of-roots-cant-be-proved

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I don't think this answers his question. He is asking about "a given $x$ is a root", not about "$\exists$ roots" (and quite surely not about "$\exists$ integer roots").

Comment: From what I recall, there are various not-quite-equivalent notions of real numbers around in constructive mathematics. Which one do you want?

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Odd, I didn't know that the "standard foundations of mathematics" was constructive...

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Oh, I read "constructive example" as "example in constructive logic".